# winform(C#) connect remote oracle database

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle

I meet a problem in developing winform (C#) project. 
How can the client from one computer of the local network A connect the oracle database which is in one computer of network B (A and B are not in the same local network).

Answer (score 4):

Possible solutions :

- Setting up a vpn to access the network where the Oracle database is hosted.
- Setting up ssh (similar to vpn) (http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_connect_tunnels.html)
- Directly expose the server and port Oracle is running on to the internet, you'll need a static ip for this to work (not recommended).
- Setting up a connection manager on a dmz server

Comment: which one do you most prefer above except the vpn(for the server is remote)

Comment: If vpn is not an option then I would go for an ssh tunnel. Note that vpn uses ssh as underlying protocol and will also work for remote server